# Handling errors from Express API with Vue

Tags: node.js, json, express, vue.js, axios

I'm having some difficulty accessing the JSON object returned with a 400 error.

The response from my Vue app is only error 400, without the JSON data.

```
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)
```

The response from the same using Postman returns both the error code and the message.

How do I access the JSON response in my Vue app?

```
{
    "error": "Email already exists!"
}
```

Express API code:

`res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email already exists!' });`

My Vue code:

```
handleSubmit () {
  this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/create', this.user)
      .then(response => {
          const status = JSON.parse(response.status)
          if (status === 200) router.push('/users')
      })
      // why doesn't the json response show
      .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use `response` property or `error` object:

```
handleSubmit () {
  this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/create', this.user)
      .then(response => {
          // if on server side you use only status 200, here it's always true
          if (response.status=== 200) {
            router.push('/users');
          }
      })
      .catch(error => {
          // error.response can be null
          if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
              console.log(error.response.data.error);
          }
      })
}
```

[See](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) documentation of axios error handling

Comment: Thank you, this worked. The issue for me was that:  `console.log(error)` returned error info as shown below, where are  `console.log(error.response)` showed a usable object.

    `Error: Request failed with status code 400
        at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
        at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
        at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)`

Answer (score 0):

Try send instead of json? Also perhaps accessing error.

```
BACKEND
res.status(400).send({ error: 'Email already exists!' })

FRONTEND
(err) => { console.log(err["error"]) }
```

Comment: Hmm... hard to say then. This is how we have it set on a PWA we're building.

Comment: Continuing to read more about this, it's looking like it might be to do with Axios.

Comment: Ah I see, I am using fetch for mine. Axios might have different requirements.